# Memory mapped files in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

When we say MongoDB uses memory mapped files, does it mean the entire dataset is loaded into memory or just the indexes? I need a clear,lucid picture of how Memory mapped files works in MongoDB.

Comment: This really is a little too broad and also not really a programming question under the site guidelines. Probably best explained to you by reading the [FAQ Section MongoDB Storage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/). The official documentation is a good source for learning, and if you have a more specific issue then feel free to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, data is not instantly or eagerly loaded into memory, it is loaded into what is known as your working set (memory) by pattern of accession.

So if you query:

```
db.c.find({a:1})
```

And have one index on `a` without the query being covered, it will fault the documents that match the query as well the index ranges it required to query to satisfy the query.

But it will only do this once you go to actually query.

You can make MongoDB eager load into resident memory (not quite actual memory but close enough) by using commands like touch (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) or by using a script of your most common queries (which will actually load into the working set, or rather RAM).

mmap maps to what is known as virtual memory, this is essentially the OS' map of memory, however, it can be a lot larger than actual memory, as already referenced, the documentation can provide more than I can here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/ also to understand a bit more about virtual memory: http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/BasicMemoryManagement